# When I manipulate the dom, v-for no longer stays in sync with a reactive array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

It's very confusing - and I would even think there's a bug here.

https://jsbin.com/qadunor/edit?html,js,output

```
updateList(containerDom) {
  return () => {
    Array.from(containerDom.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item")).forEach((domItem, idx) => {
      let listItemIndex = this.list.findIndex(listItem => listItem.name === domItem.innerText)
      let listItem = this.list[listItemIndex]
      listItem.pos = idx
      this.list.splice(listItemIndex, 1, listItem)
    })
  }
}
```

If you drag the first list-item ("animal") to the last list-item ("armband") to essentially do a swap (using Sortable.js), you'll see that the list is reactive - you can see it in the output - it updated its position, but the "v-for" loop didn't react properly.

It reacts in some way - but not correctly as you'll see (it incorrectly drops armband into the second position). Now, if I were to just use Sortable.js straight up the swap works fine (ie if I don't handle the onUpdate event - just comment it out). I know I could use VUE.draggable (or whatever it is called, where it maintains an internal list, but for a variety of more complicated reasons I can't use that library). My use-case where I want to use the above technique is irrelevant here - I just want to know why this very particular way fails for "v-for".

I know it has something to do with the fact that Sortable.js does it's own DOM manipulation, but I would expect that once the list array is mutated, that the v-for loop should react appropriately - but it's as if gets confused by what is currently in the DOM.

Comment: could you not make a duplicate array and manipulate that instead? Changing the array you're using is generally not a good idea

Comment: I've tried that - it doesn't make a difference. Updating the array via splice is totally fine anyway. It is reactively changing the array ... It's the virtual dom that doesn't properly render the new order.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for this not working is quite simply because I manipulate the dom directly (via Sortable.js), but when it comes to updating the virtual dom that vue manages, it doesn't know about the dom manipulations that have happened, and doesn't properly update the virtual dom (and thereby the real dom) when the reactive list changes.

It could be seen as a bug on vue's side - I expect the "v-for" loop to reflect the reactive list. But it could also be seen as a limitation. It's a tradeoff - vuejs can't inspect the real dom as well as the virtual dom for performance reasons?

So to deal with this I'd probably need

- to let the drag and drop happen and let the dom be manipulated directly (via Sortable.js),
- then inspect the new order in the dom and make notes on the new order,
- then reverse the dom manipulations,
- and then use the notes I took and update the reactive list,
- which will then in turn update the virtual dom.

So the step that is missing in my sample code, is the code that reverses the dom manipulations.

Anyway - that's just my understanding of why the code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant was you could creating an exact duplicate of your current list and then have all the names be swapping around (I'm not sure why you're making it overly complicated by using a forEach, since the `updateList` function passes an `oldIndex` and `newIndex`)

```
  data() {
     let list = [
        { name: "animal", pos: 0 },
        { name: "aloe", pos: 1 },
        { name: "arm", pos: 2 },
        { name: "arsenal", pos: 3 },
        { name: "antenna", pos: 4 },
        { name: "antler", pos: 5 },
        { name: "armband", pos: 6 },
      ]
    return {
      original_list: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list)),
      list: list,
    };    
  },

  methods: {
    listToJSON(list) {
      return JSON.stringify(list, null, 2)
    },
    updateList(context) {
      let old = context.oldIndex
      let $new = context.newIndex
      let temp_name = this.original_list[old].name
      this.original_list[old].name = this.original_list[$new].name
      this.original_list[$new].name = temp_name
    }
  },
```

https://jsbin.com/pulapopave/1/edit?html,js,output